# Описание функций в сборке SharpPCAP

Tags: .net

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где можно достать перечень и описание классов и функций, входящих в состав сборки **SharpPCAP**?

Какие функции использовать для **перехвата** и **разбора** пакетов, посылаемых через порт?

Спасибо!

Comment: У меня при компиляции вываливается исключение. Ничего не могу найти на эту тему...
Не удается загрузить DLL "wpcap": Не найден указанный модуль. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Answer (score 1):

Вся документация по SharpPCAP лежит на SourceForge:

- [общий обзор](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/sharppcap/index.php?title=Main_Page#API_documentation),
- [документация](http://sharppcap.sourceforge.net/htmldocs/).

Примеры использования пакета лежат там же. [Пример №4](http://sharppcap.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=sharppcap/sharppcap;a=blob_plain;f=Tutorial/index.html;hb=HEAD#basicCapNoCallback):

```
// Извлечь устройство из списка
ICaptureDevice device = devices[i];

// Открыть устройство для захвата
int readTimeoutMilliseconds = 1000;
device.Open(DeviceMode.Promiscuous, readTimeoutMilliseconds);

Packet packet = null;

// Хранить пакеты, используя GetNextPacket()
while((packet=device.GetNextPacket()) != null )
{
    // Печать времени и длины каждого полученного пакета
    DateTime time = packet.PcapHeader.Date;
    int len = packet.PcapHeader.PacketLength;
    Console.WriteLine(
        "{0}:{1}:{2},{3} Len={4}",
        time.Hour,
        time.Minute,
        time.Second,
        time.Millisecond, 
        len
    );
}

// Закрыть устройство PCAP
device.Close();
```